# How to handle express.js csrf exception nicely?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I have an expressjs server with csrf running.  I guess because I have three subdomains running on different expressjs servers, sometimes they got screw up on the cookie and throw this:

> Error: Forbidden at Object.exports.error
>   (/home/ubuntu/web/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
>   at createToken
>   (/home/ubuntu/web/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
>   at
>   /home/ubuntu/web/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:7
>   at Object.ondone
>   (/home/ubuntu/web/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2/index.js:46:8)

This is ugly.   So, how should I capture this exception / error nicely and just output a res.send() with some nicely error message?

In addition, in my case, because 3 subdomains (of the same domain) run by 3 different express servers, all use csrf.  It seems that it doesn't work nicely together.  Is there a way to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work nicely, a subdomain is considered another domain, and CSRF protection in Express adds a token to all forms to avoid forgery. I believe you can avoid the issues by running just one server and setting up the subdomains with virtualhosts.

Comment: The problem is.. the subdomains are for different purpose.. 
like   www.whatever.com
dev.whatever.com
build.whatever.com

therefore, they are run by different server code. and I put csrf for each of them.

Comment: And you can use Express virtualhosts to set up those subdomains to run on the same server, but with different settings and routes, and then the CSRF sent by the browser would always match the server, as it's always the same server, and not three different servers.

Comment: i had virtual host running for some other subdomains.  As you can see, I have subdomains like www (production), dev, build, qa..etc  Some of them are for development purpose and need to be run in different server, because of testing & security concern.   However, under same root domain, the csrf fail.  I even have specific domain for cookie (not just *).